# Reading images from a directory and show them on the screen

Tags: c#

I can reach with foreach to directory but, because of working  like stack, I only reach last picture in the directory. I have lot of image that starting 1.jpg until 100.

```
namespace deneme_readimg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\DENEME");

            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            textBox1.Text = file.Name; 
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do `textBox1.Text += file.Name + " ";` and be more specific

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx

Comment: @DavidMartin +1, you should post that as answer (maybe with a little explanation).

Comment: why not gridview or another control to show the image details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @LarsKristensen I'm posting my comment as an answer.

I would use the [AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) method, unless your requirement is to add to the text box on every click I would first make a call to [Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear.aspx).

```
namespace deneme_readimg
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\DENEME");

            // Clear the contents first
            textBox1.Clear();
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                // Append each item
                textBox1.AppendText(file.Name); 
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what you are asking or what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to see all of the names, you could change the foreach loop into:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + file.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

for displaying just File name. Use a multiline textbox

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())       
   sb.Append(file.Name + Environment.NewLine); 

textBox1.Text =sb.ToString().Trim();
```

if you want to show images then you need to use some datacontainer like `ListBox` or `DataGridView` and add row for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Just collect all the data you need to output in StringBuilder;
when ready publish it:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\DENEME");

// Let's collect all the file names in a StringBuilder
// and only then assign them to the textBox. 
StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles()) {
  if (Sb.Length > 0) 
    Sb.Append(" "); // <- or Sb.AppendLine(); if you want each file printed on a separate line

  Sb.Append(file.Name);
}

// One assignment only; it prevents you from flood of "textBox1_TextChanged" calls
textBox1.Text = Sb.ToString();
```